# AWS ALB setting Cache-Control private max-age header

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, caching, load-balancing

I have a Symfony 3 application that is deployed on an AWS Beanstalk instance with one EC2 instance behind an Application Load Balancer since I use HTTP/2.

I have found a weird problem with the load balancer however.I know that it should not set any caching headers, but for some reason it does.On my testing machine, using the same code, I have this header sent with the response:

```
cache-control:private
```

But on the AWS server this header is sent instead:

```
cache-control:private, max-age=86400
```

This break my application since I do not want the client's browser to cache the response since my application should only be accessed by logged in users.The only way I have found to fix this is by calling this function in my app.php file before sending the response back to the client:

```
$response->headers->removeCacheControlDirective('private');
```

This adds the `no-cache` directive to the `cache-control` header which prevents the browser from caching the response, but I am not sure if this is the right approach since the AWS app still sends the `max-age` directive and I am not sure the `no-cache` directive overwrites the others in all browsers.

After the fix this is what I get from my server:

```
cache-control:no-cache, private
```

And this from AWS:

```
cache-control:no-cache, private, max-age=86400
```

TL/DR: So, what I am asking, is there any way to remove the `max-age` directive from what the AWS server sends?

Thank you, I have used StackOverflow for many years but this is the first time I am asking a questions since I have not found the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have finally found the answer and it turns out it has nothing to do with AWS...
The reason for this is that in my .htaccess file I had a `mod_expires` directive with this line on it:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 days"
```

Which added that cache header to all html pages...And for some reason neither my Apache on Linux or on Windows had mod_expires on but the web server from AWS had it...